# Error Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I perform a simple ajax request I get the following error

> TypeError: 'toString' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLAnchorElement.

This is my ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function(){
        $("#tabla_persona table tr").click(function() {
            var cod = $( "#identificador",this);
            alert(cod.html());

            var parametros={
                "cod":cod
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo site_url("archivo/prueba"); ?>',
                data: parametros, 
                success: function(resp) { 
                   $("#tabla_usuario_individual").html(resp);
                }
            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller

```
public function prueba(){
    $this->load->view('datos_persona');

}
```

and my simple page to see the result

```
<a>
Prueba
    </a>
```

Comment: What type of element is `#identificador`?

Comment: You're passing a jQuery object (`cod`) as data `var parametros={"cod":cod};`

Comment: <div class="row" id="tabla_usuario_individual" name="tabla_usuario_individual"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
        var parametros={
            "cod":cod
        };
```

to:

```
        var parametros={
            "cod":cod.html()
        };
```

Comment: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/PROYDW3/index.php/archivo/prueba"

Answer (score 0):

Just need simple change.I think the following code will work.

```
public function prueba(){
  echo $this->load->view('datos_persona',true);
}
```